# What is the robot's power source in the 2018 reboot of Lost in Space?

Tags: lost-in-space, lost-in-space-2018

Whilst watching the reboot I wondered what the robot's power source is. Obviously it's not being charged at any point and there are no scenes (that I've seen - up to episode 3 but happy to have spoilers regarding power source) that cover how it maintains the power to push huge stones, trees and just maintain itself.

So how is the robot maintaining it's power?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't know.

In Season 2 it is put into a deep cave with no access to sun or anything except rock and dirt. Yet it appears to be still powered.

A possibility from known technology: the robot may have a compact fusion reactor, which could be compact (no minimum critical mass), and use very little fuel (compare nuclear submarines that spend months without refueling), or even extract water vapor from the surroundings for fuel. And it naturally produces intense heat, which is used frequently by the robots. (Or perhaps the aliens finally figured out cold fusion.)

That's just one conjecture. In any case, a civilization that creates interstellar rifts in space probably can probably create a long-lasting portable power source.

Comment: Hey Paul - belated thanks for this answer, marking as accepted until we find out anymore on the show

Comment: https://xkcd.com/2115/